# Add an new option to a package

Tags: packages, package-options

I have made a package called byzantinemusic( see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/byzantinemusic) One could use this package to write music in modern byzantine notation using the command 
`\usepackage{byzantinemusic}` at the preamble. I have already designed a new .sty with name `byzantinemusicextended.sty` that extends the package to the  archaic byzantine music notation. I would like to give the ''archaic'' option  to my package so  that:
 if one use  `\usepackage[archaic]{byzantinemusic}`  then  byzantinemusicextended.sty will be used, otherwise(i.e. without the option) the old `byzantinemusic.sty` is used. How could this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example

```
\ProvidesPackage{mytest}
\newif\ifmyoption
% false by default
\DeclareOption{test}{\myoptiontrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifmyoption
  \RequirePackage{amsmath}
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
\newcommand\test{test}
```

Thus `\test` is only defined without the `test` option. MWE that uses it

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mytest}
%\usepackage[test]{mytest}
\begin{document}
dsf

\test
\end{document}
```

Thus if `test` is given, `amsmath` is loaded and `\test` is undefined. Without `test` `amsmath` is not loaded and `\test` is defined.

Idea taken from `empheq.sty` which I remembered used a similar trick

Comment: I haven't a computer next to me but I 'll test your answer later. Just a question. If I define test command in different way lets say \newcommand\test{you have entered test option} after amsmath package then is it ok or the Latex is going to complain?

Comment: @kornaros not sure what you mean. Here `\test` it just an example of what might be in your byzantinemusic package, macros that might not be available when the extended package is loaded instead

Comment: I just asked if one could have the same command with 2 different meaning(inside option the test will have a different meaning)!   Another question. Is it possible to extend your answer so that one could have 2 or more options like [testI], [testII] Thanks!

Comment: There are many other answers on this site about package options so search them up (not at a pc). If you look at the code I gave you loading of mytest stops right after loading amsmath, so if the package loaded there (here amsmath is an example) provides `\test` then that version is used.